# Rails 3 - Factory girl and sequence for belongs_to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory, factory-bot

I have 2 models - **User** and **Teacher**. **Teacher** belongs_to **User**, **User** has **Teacher**.

So, i use Factory girl gem:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.user_login "Another User"
  user.user_role "admin"
  user.password "foobar"
end

Factory.sequence :user_login do |n|
  "person-#{n}"
end

Factory.define :teacher do |teacher|
  ...
  teacher.user                                                                            
end
```

I met problem and i don't understand how to solve that. When i create user via factory i can easily write:

```
@user = Factory( :user, :user_login => Factory.next(:user_login)  )
```

And this creates user with inique login.

How can i do same thing for teacher? I tried that:

```
@teacher = Factory( :teacher, :user_login => Factory.next(:user_login)  )
```

And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that.

```
@teacher = Factory( :teacher, 
                    :user => Factory(:user, :user_login => Factory.next(:user_login)) )
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to specify sequences separately and then pass them to another factory - you can use them inside factories like this:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  # ...
  user.sequence(:user_login) { |n| "person=#{n}" }
end
```

or shorter

```
Factory.define :user do
  # ...
  sequence(:user_login) { |n| "person=#{n}" }
end
```

Then, to association a user with teacher:

```
Factory.define :teacher do
  association :user
end
```

Then you can just call

```
@teacher = Factory(:teacher)
```

which will automatically create the associated user with the next user_login in the sequence.